# Java : Logging on demand on production

Tags: logging, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, javaagents

I am working on a legacy software developed in swing and core java. I wanted to add a logging feature in the system where

1. If something goes wrong in production system admin can enable logging without shutting down/restarting application.
2. Admin will redo the steps to create logs.
3. Once bug is reproduced admin can disable the logging and can upload logs to support site.

I am thinking of using AspectJ and I also wanted to collect logs only for a particular section of application.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
-Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with AspectJ by adding a boolean switch to the system and evaluating it with `if()` pointcuts.